# como posso definir 10 itens por listview?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso mostrar 10 itens por página no listview?

Adapter:

```
 ThreadsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<MessageThread> objects, ThreadsActivity threadsActivity, Query ordenar) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.dataUpdateAfterDelete=threadsActivity;
    this.messageThreadObjects = (ArrayList<MessageThread>) objects;
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    messageThread = getItem(position);
    ThreadsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.threads_listview, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.threadTitleTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.threadTitleTV);
        viewHolder.nombretema = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombretema);
        viewHolder.messagethreadsTimeTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.messagethreadsTimeTV);
        viewHolder.numCommentsTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.numCommentsTV);
        viewHolder.deleteThreadButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteThreadButton);
        viewHolder.comentariosTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comentariosTV);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        if (!messageThread.user_id.equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
            viewHolder.deleteThreadButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.deleteThreadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    viewHolder.nombretema.setText(messageThread.user_name);
    viewHolder.threadTitleTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    viewHolder.threadTitleTV.setText(messageThread.title);
```

Activity :

```
public void getThreads() {
    mDatabase.child("Normas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Query ordenar = mDatabase.child("Normas").orderByChild("countthreads");
            threadsList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot messageThreadSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Query ordenar1 = mDatabase.child("Normas").orderByChild("countthreads");
                MessageThread messageThread = messageThreadSnapshot.getValue(MessageThread.class);
                if (messageThread != null) {
                    messageThread.thread_id = messageThreadSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + messageThread.toString());
                }
                threadsList.add(messageThread);
            }
            threadsAdapter = new ThreadsAdapter(ThreadsActivity.this, R.layout.threads_listview, threadsList, ThreadsActivity.this, ordenar);
            Collections.reverse(threadsList);
            threadsListView.setAdapter(threadsAdapter);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ThreadsActivity.this, "ThreadsActivity: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```